# How can I move my navbar links to the right of the navbar?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm making a portfolio and would like my name to be on the left of the `navbar` and the `navbar` list items to be on the right. I used the float:right property but it didn't move the list items to the right. Here is my code. I'm using bootstrap btw.

```
  <nav class = "navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <h1> Aiya Siddig</h1>
    <ul class = "navbar-nav">
        <li class = "nav-item">
            <a class = "nav-link" href = "index.html"> About Me </a>
        </li>
        <li class = "nav-item">
            <a class = "nav-link" href = "portfolio.html"> Portfolio </a>
        </li>
        <li class = "nav-item">
            <a class = "nav-link" href = "contact.html"> Contact </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
 .nav-link, .nav-item  {
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align:right;
        float:right;

    }
    
    h1 {
        color: rgb(236, 236, 236);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `native` bootstrap responsive [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) `classes` like `d-flex` and `justify-content-between` in your `nav` to move your links to the right of navbar

To `color` your `h1` you can simply use the class `text-white` to show the name as white `color`.

**Live Demo:**

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark d-flex justify-content-between">
 <h1 class="text-white"> Aiya Siddig</h1>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="index.html"> About Me </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html"> Portfolio </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html"> Contact </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @AiyaSiddig You are welcome - glad to help you. Do not forget to mark the answer as accepted. Thanks :)